# Field Reference Module Problem

Tags: entities

I have created 2 content types :

1. Team (Fields: Title, Logo (Image Field)
2. Game (Date, Team "A", Team "B")

Created a Reference Field at Game content type to pull the logo of each team.

However, when I create a new View table format, everything displays fine, but at the frontpage where I get this message:

> Strict warning: Only variables should be passed by reference in >field_reference_field_formatter_view() (line 316 of >/Users/*****/sites/all/modules/field_reference/field_reference.module).

This is line 316 of views.module

```
$field_entity = !empty($item['entity_id']) ?
```

I can see that there's something about the fact that the Field Reference is pulling a .JPG file but there's no proper formatter in Views (default, teaser, etc),

Don't know how to correct this,(not a developer) any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The better option is that you should select a formatter for the image field so that your views work properly when displaying logo images on to it.